# SSIS How can I use a query from a table in one server to select data in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have two unlinked servers one production and one reporting. I'm using an SSIS package to incrementally update a table on the reporting server. On the reporting server I have a staging table that lists items that need to be updated or imported. Currently I have a data flow task that pulls the source table from the source server, does a look up with the staging table and then updates the destination table. My problem with this is I don't want to have to pull the entire source table everytime I run the update. Is there a way to use the staging table from reporting server to select data from the the production server? Basically I want my data source query to look something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM ProductionDatabase.SourceTable 
WHERE SourceTable.Key IN (SELECT Key FROM ReportingDatabase.StagingTable)
```

Thank you for looking at this. I'm new to SSIS and could definitely use some help.

[image: Current SSIS Data Flow]

Comment: Linking the servers is the path I would choose.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS allows you to use a Merge transformation, which should allow you to do what you want to do. That's one of the strengths of SSIS, which is that it can mix and match data from disparate data sources. So, do this as part of your SSIS data flow and don't try to do it with direct SQL.

This assumes that the key is a unique value, otherwise you might need to tweak things so that the number of rows doesn't expand, but you should be able to use the Merge then conditionally pass along rows only if a match is found.

Comment: So a merge transformation won't require the entire table from source to be loaded?

Comment: SSIS will have to bring it into memory most likely, but it doesn't have to be loaded into your destination database.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want to have to read the entire table into memory. I don't mind so much the load on the SSIS server but I don't want to lock the source table for more than a few seconds if I can help it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to lock the table. Also, SSIS can be pretty fast. Does the table number in the 10's or 100's of millions of rows?